# Limiting administrative shapefile to less granular level using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, dissolve, administrative-boundaries

I am using an administrative shapefile of Jamaica in ArcGIS Pro. I have a number of attributes at varying levels of granularity. There are 14 Parishes, 65 "Constituencies", roughly 650 "Communities" and roughly 5700 enumeration districts. I want to view the boundaries at the level of the "Community", however currently they are displayed at the enumeration district level, the most granular. I am very new to ArcGIS, so I am doing a lot of trial and error.

Could someone explain how I can filter out more granular divisions (in this case enumeration districts), so that I will just be left with a map of boundaries at administrative level I want to study(communities)?

I have tried doing "Select By Attributes" but that does not seem to allow me to select an entire administrative level unless I go one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) by community column:

> Aggregates features based on specified attributes.

[image]